# How can I use a string as an object or a class

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to get a string from firestore and use it as a color on a container but I need to use the string I get as a color.

```
color: Colors.{snapshot.data.data()['color']}
```

this code doesn't work but it is how I want to use the string I get and use it as a color.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking

Comment: what is the value of `snapshot.data.data()['color']`? Any example?

Comment: red, green, lightGreenAccent, ...

Comment: Perhaps a package such as https://pub.dev/packages/from_css_color might do what you want? (I've never used this particular package.  There are a number of similar packages.)

Comment: Consider a general https://pub.dev/packages/enum_to_string package for this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `snapshot.data.data()['color']` is an `int`

```
c = snapshot.data.data()['color'];
color: Color(c)
```

or simply

```
color: Color(snapshot.data.data()['color'])
```

---

if it is not an integer then you'll have to parse it.

Comment: it's not an integer it is a string like red, yellow ...

Comment: Then it will be a problem. You can't just convert strings like red,yellow to a Color. If there are fixed number of strings then you can use a map but it won't be managable when there are lots of them. If color is an `int` or a hex string like `"FFFFFFFF"` then it becomes very managable.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `snapshot.data.data()['color']` to int, like `0XFFFF0000`.
If you can't do this, you can make a map like this:

```dart
Map<String, int> colorMap = {"red": 0xFFFF0000, "green": 0XFF00FF00, "blue": 0XFF0000FF};

color: Color(colorMap[snapshot.data.data()['color']])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store the colors in a list and get the color by index from firestore like this

```
List<Color> colorsList = [Colors.red,Colors.blue];

color: colorsList[snapshot.data.get('colorIndex')];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of enumerations, this is very easy.

```
void main() {
  final green = _get('green', Color.values);
  print(green);
  final red = _get('red', Color.values);
  print(red);
  final status = _get('accepted', Status.values);
  print(status);
  print(status.runtimeType);
}

T _get<T>(String name, Iterable<T> values) {
  final fullname = '$T.$name';
  for (final value in values) {
    if (value.toString() == fullname) {
      return value;
    }
  }

  throw StateError('Value nof fount: $name');
}

enum Color { red, green, blue }

enum Status { accepted, rejected }
```

Output:

```
Color.green
Color.red
Status.accepted
Status
```